# How to Run Timer if the App goes to Background?

Tags: ios, swift

I try to run a Function in SceneDelegate.swift if the App goes to Background.

if the App entering the Background the Timer Stops. 
**if have added the Background Modes and select the Background Processing.**

but timer stops everytime!

```
func runtimerAction(){
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
        print("Timer fired!")
    }
}


func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {

    runtimerAction()

    (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveContext()
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do here is not possible; you cannot run indefinitely in the background. What actual problem are you trying to solve (clearly you want to do more than print to the console)? There are likely many answers already on StackOverflow.

Comment: i try to send failed requests if network is available from coredata.

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple's restrictions your app need background mode to do anything in background and even then you still can't run a timer on background.

If you need a counter to check how much time has passed since X can save the time (I.E: `Date()`) and then check against the saved time to see how much time has passed since app last went to background.

Comment: i try to send failed requests saved in coredata if network is available

Comment: IF you are okay with waiting until app comes into foreground to send them, simply save the failed request in coredata, and when app comes back to foreground check coredata for requests, send them and when it's successful remove them from coredata

if not, then you should use background tasks (https://www.raywenderlich.com/5817-background-modes-tutorial-getting-started), timers can't run on background.